# How to hide the first column in a SMARTY displayed Table?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm importing data from an array into a table using SMARTY. However the first row and column should not be displayed. I'm successfully hiding the row however my if statement for the column does nothing at all.

```
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
   {foreach from=$numFlocks item=foo}
     <th>Flock {$foo}</th>
   {/foreach}
 </tr>

{section loop=$flock[1] name=unit}
  <tr {if $smarty.section.first}style="display:none"{/if}
      {if $smarty.section.unit.first}style="display:none"{/if}>
{foreach from=$flock item=foo}
    <td>{$foo[unit]}</td>
{/foreach}
   </tr>
{/section}

</table>
```

Currently the tables index at the top is correct creating 3 columns. However the rows for the first column are blank and the rest are pushed over making a new column.

Comment: Can't you do the logic when you identify $numFlocks and just display the data you have in smarty without having to exclude anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `{foreach}` loop a name, and then you can use `.first` just like you do with your `{section}` loop:

```
{foreach from=$flock item=foo name=flock_loop}
    {if !$smarty.foreach.flock_loop.first}
         <td>{$foo[unit]}</td>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```